# "Student Jacob was in Italy" - is "student", here, an adjective or a noun?

Tags: british-english, past-participles, attributive-nouns

I am currently writing a paper on British newspaper articles; however, I keep on encountering constructions such as:

"**Student** Jacob was in Italy" or 
 "**jailed** Samantha said yesterday..."

where words that my books say are nouns seem to be being used as adjectives? I would be grateful if someone could tell me if these nouns, in these instances, become adjectives?

Comment: *Student* is an attributive noun. *Jailed* is not a noun at all; it is a past/passive participle employed as an adjective.

Comment: Your ***student*** is an [attributive noun](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/attributive_noun) usage, but ***jailed*** could never be a noun - it's a [***past participle** used as attributive adjective*](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/past-participle-as-attributive-adjective.2659587/)

Comment: @StoneyB: Snap! (Or "Jinx", as I believe the younger generation say! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your response is clearly superior, since you took the trouble to post links to definitions.

Comment: "jailed could never be a noun"... never, ever, ever? _The jailed started a riot._ — I'm the first to admit it's not the most beautiful English, but you can use a lot of past participles as nouns, _if you really want to_. (Whether you should want to is another matter.)

Comment: One might ask a question whether *I keep on discovering* is less appropriate here (*ie*, in this context) than *I keep discovering*.

Comment: @StoneyB: I'd be interested to see if someone (perhaps OP himself) can explain why some learners might mistake ***jailed*** here for a "noun usage". Where there's an actual *misunderstanding* (as opposed to a simple ***lack of** understanding*), I feel a ***good*** answer should address the cause of the incorrect assumptions, as well as simply spelling out the correct answer. (As ever, I see oerkelens is on the ball on that front! :)

Comment: @pazzo: *To keep **on** [verbing]* is a somewhat colloquial version, but otherwise means exactly the same as *to keep [verbing]*.

Comment: The two phrases do not express the same meaning or vibe, if you prefer that word. @FumbleFingers which is why I said 'appropriate'. And also 'might'. And not 'grammatical'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I know English is much less willing to employ PaPpls, and adjectives generally, as nouns than other European languages. My impression is that this is only natural when the adjective can be taken to name a *category*.

Comment: @StoneyB: Indeed. It can be a very "loosely-defined" category, as in *My greatest fear is the unknown*. It's kinda interesting that OP's ***jailed*** example could reasonably be preceded by ***the*** (which seems to be the norm, if not actually *required*, in most similar constructions). I think even in response to *How d'you want your eggs? Fried or boiled?* you could get away with *I'll have **the** boiled [eggs], please*, though personally I probably wouldn't usually include the article.

Comment: @FumbleFingers A few adjectives have been 'categorized' by long use: *the rich, the wicked*, and many are sort of inherently 'categorical': *adverbials,infinitives*. And any may be categorized in the discourse itself; I think that's what happens in your egg example.

Comment: @StoneyB: Absolutely agree. It seems to me what I said about the definite article actually *flows* from your point about "named categories" - either well-established, like *the rich, the poor*, or "contextually-relevant category created on the fly", like *the boiled*. In both cases there's only *one* such category, so specifically identifying it as ***the** [PaPpl used as noun]* seems perfectly natural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question simply: an attributive noun is still a noun, it does not *become* an adjective.

As several commenters have noted, *student* is being used as an attributive noun, and *jailed* is being used as an attributive adjective. This doesn't change their classification. Let's take them one at a time.

First, we have "*Student* Jacob..." with *student* as an attributive noun. Student is still a description of a (type of) person, even though it is adding itself as an attribute to the proper noun of Jacob. Take it alone, without the proper noun, and we still have a proper sentence: "A student was in Italy."

Next, we have "*Jailed* Samantha..." with *jailed* as an attributive adjective. The phrase of *Jailed Samantha* may be part of a noun phrase, but the word *jailed* is still an adjective.

As brought up by the commenters, there is another related type of adjective called a [Nominalized Adjective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalized_adjective) which can be used in place of a noun. Take the following sentence:

> *Jailed* protesters began a hunger strike, insisting on joining the ***freed***.

Both *jailed* and *freed* are adjectives describing protesters. The first one, *jailed*, is an attributive adjective and is part of the noun phrase *Jailed protesters*. *Freed* is a nominalized adjective which also describes the protesters, but is being used in place of a noun.

Most importantly, however, if the words ***protesters*** and ***the*** were removed from the example sentence, it would no longer make sense. Attributive adjectives and nominalized adjectives still have to define or qualify nouns, even if the definition or qualification is implied.